# How to use standard linting for Jasmine files that reference functions?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, specifications, lint, linter

I am using https://github.com/feross/standard

When I run it against a Jasmine spec it complains about functions that are called not being defined.
This seems to be because they are defined in other files.
All the files are all included in the actual SpecRunner.html file itself

The file I am running has `/* es-lint jasmine */` at the top of it.  Other files do not.

How do I get the linter to recognize that the functions are in the other file.